# Blocking specific MAC address from contacting me

Tags: networking, lan

Could I block a specific MAC address on my LAN from contacting me?

I know I could do it from router or switch.

But I wanna learn if it is possible in Ubuntu(Linux) commands.

Comment: Check your router manual.

Comment: I want to do it in Ubuntu. Is it possible?

Comment: The `mac` tag is about Macintosh computers...

Comment: The **tag** is about Macintosh computers, see [taginfo](http://askubuntu.com/tags/mac/info)

Comment: @EeroAaltonen Ok i got you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can drop from a source MAC address, yeah:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:AA -j DROP
```

Obviously, you'll need to change that address.

If you want to make that permanent, make sure `ufw` is installed and then edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` to have something like this before the COMMIT:

```
-A ufw-before-input -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:AA -j DROP
```

Comment: And if your machine has other iptables rules set up (e.g. configured as a router), then to function, the `DROP` rule has to be before them in the list, to take precedence. Then use `-I INPUT` ("insert at pos 1"), not `-A INPUT` ("append").