# How do I extract the source MAC from a [UFW BLOCK] entry?

Tags: ufw

I have the following UFW Block entry. How do I get the source MAC? I'm getting a ton from the same MAC=e8:11:32:cb:d9:42:54:04:a6:ba:22:f8:08:00 doing port scanning. If it matters, I'm using 12.04 LTS.

```
Feb  4 17:46:06 ChromeBox-Server kernel: [663960.096168] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=e8:11:32:cb:d9:42:54:04:a6:ba:22:f8:08:00 SRC=123.129.216.39 DST=192.168.1.10 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x20 TTL=115 ID=49547 PROTO=TCP SPT=1535 DPT=22 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MAC=e8:11:32:cb:d9:42:54:04:a6:ba:22:f8:08:00` can be broken up as

- destination MAC (in this case this is the MAC address of your card, since it is an incoming packet): `e8:11:32:cb:d9:42`
- source MAC: `54:04:a6:ba:22:f8`
- [EtherType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType): `08:00`

So if you want to programmatically extract the source MAC you can do something like this:

```
cat ufw.log | awk '{print $11}' | cut -d ':' -f7-12
```

Comment: This makes sense. Now to block that source MAC.

Comment: @user244712 That question was asked and answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/410023/blocking-specific-mac-address-from-contacting-me-on-local-network

Comment: Haven't seen any log activity since I blocked that MAC. I used: iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m mac --mac-source 54:04:a6:ba:22:f8 -j REJECT

Comment: And iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m mac --mac-source 54:04:a6:ba:22:f8 -j REJECT

Comment: What's the difference in REJECT or DROP? Answer: REJECT sends a response. DROP just doesn't respond at all forcing a timeout.

Comment: @user244712 You won't see logs for those which are blocked with the iptables rule. Simple iptables rules are not automatically logged, you have to define a log rule if you want to log them. I don't understand your last comment: If you know the difference between the two, why are you asking? :)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your network settings may be using IPv6, as `MAC=e8:11:32:cb:d9:42:54:04:a6:ba:22:f8:08:00` is an IPv6 address, probably that of your current network connection. A true MAC (Media Access Control) address would only be six groups of hex digits: `aa:bb:11:12:34:56`.

The teller in this is the `DPT=22`. They are trying to find open SSH ports. This is fine if you don't have port 22 open (which I generally don't recommend). If you do have/need port 22 open, I hope your username/password combo is robust. You might also want to check out something like [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which will impose temporary blocks after a number of failed login attempts, including SSH logins.

If you're constantly getting port-scanned by the same IP - `SRC=123.129.216.39` - set up a `DENY` or `DROP` rule in UFW for that IP. `sudo ufw deny from 123.129.216.39`

Comment: I already have Fail2Ban up and running. No, SSH isn't on port 22. This is just one of numerous open port attempts. All on standard ports. It's probably a script kiddie since they haven't bothered to spoof the MAC because the MACs are all the same.

Comment: Is the source IP rotating? Just curious. I was getting hit hard for a few days with attempts on my SMTP server from a group of IPs. +1 for Fail2Ban - nice to have that watching your back.

Comment: Yep. IP was bouncing around but the MAC was the same. Haven't had any log activity since I blocked that MAC.

Comment: It's not an IPv6 IP address.