# Find MAC address in the filesystem

Tags: networking, configuration, ifconfig

My laptop is down, but I need to extract its MAC address thas was previously used to establish wifi connection. The filesystem was cloned, so I am trying to find any configurational file which contains the string with MAC address. What file is usually red by ifconfig to display network interfaces information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**: `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

**Option 2:** `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory, inspect any of the files for connections listed there.

**Options 3**: `/var/log/syslog` file and archived ones, `syslog.*.gz`. Specifically, look for something in format `date hostname dhclient: Listening on LPF/wlan0/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

**Option 4**: May be listed in `dmesg` log as well, however at least for me personally, it took form without `:` as separator. Here's what I mean

```
[    5.655159] ieee80211 phy0: hwaddr b482fed38556, RTL8187SE + rtl8225-se
```

**side note:** since `/sys` filesystem exists only at runtime , as does `/proc` , it's impossible to view `/sys/class/net/wlan0/address` file, however I will leave that as side note, in case one needs a file usable at run-time.

Comment: `/sys/` isn't real so may not exist in the clone. Option 2 only works if you specify which adapter a connection should connect on. Option 3 requires your last boot to have been fairly successful. Option 1 is the best bet.

Comment: The second option works for me. Strange, but I don't have file 70-persistent-net.rules in my filesystem

Comment: Option #2 should work in 99% of the cases, because for the most part Ubuntu users use NetworkManager, unless the user is using `wicd` or command-line only method.  @freude do you have it listed with a different starting number perhaps ?

Comment: @Oli I suspected that about `/sys` as it is a virtual file system, but it's still a file, it doesn't disappear just like that, unless its being removed upon shutdown. I will try to test that once I get home to my hard drive with 15.04.   As for option #2 , the interface is already specified when user clicks network connection through the network-manager indicator.

Comment: @Serg It's virtual; it never really exists. The files are coming from inside the house, etc. Same with things like `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run`.

Comment: `/var/log/dmesg` is also a good bet

Comment: @abligh yes, that as well. It didn't show up for me right away, because the address didn't have `:` as separator, which is why i didn't add that to my original answer. I'll add that now

Comment: `/sys` is **virtual**. It does not exist on disk. You should remove #4 from the list.

Comment: I've left `/sys` option as side note, someone may find it useful

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu server 18.04, I found the MAC address in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/ufw.log` as :

```
Dec  7 02:49:08 hostname kernel: [1870435.881302] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:yy:2b:49:c7:23:aa:bb:00:00:00:1a:08:00 SRC=XXX.YYY.114.154 DST=XXX.YYY.138.47 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=40963 DPT=80 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Dec  7 02:54:32 hostname kernel: [1870760.588719] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:yy:2b:49:c7:23:aa:bb:00:00:00:1a:08:00 SRC=XXX.YYY.25.65 DST=XXX.YYY.138.47 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=36934 PROTO=TCP SPT=2740 DPT=80 WINDOW=35007 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Dec  7 03:01:22 hostname kernel: [1871170.660324] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eno1 OUT= MAC=xx:yy:2b:49:c7:23:aa:bb:00:00:00:1a:08:00 SRC=XXX.YYY.106.221 DST=XXX.YYY.138.47 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=237 ID=1440 PROTO=TCP SPT=58914 DPT=80 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/416746/743264) to parse the log, the desired MAC address is:

```
xx:yy:2b:49:c7:23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from arp cache

cat /proc/net/arp