# Strange UFW Block Logs

Tags: networking, server, dns, firewall, ufw

i noticed repeats of the following logs in my server:

```
Dec  3 21:55:27 alice-server kernel: [287677.084885] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens18 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:90:9a:4a:dc:31:62:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

1. Should i be concerned? I noticed a few similar posts saying this is an issue with multicast DNS server in the router. I don't understand what that means, greatly appreciate a layman explaination of that.
2. My ip ranges for my home devices are 192.168.1.x so naturally when i saw an ip that is 192.168.0.1 i got alarmed! Should this be a concern? And what can i do to "boot" this ip out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DST=224.0.0.1 are IGMP Multicast discovery packets - see for example [Strange dmesg UFW messages... lots of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493167/strange-dmesg-ufw-messages-lots-of-them)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange dmesg UFW messages... lots of them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493167/strange-dmesg-ufw-messages-lots-of-them)

Comment: @Marco 

Thank you for that thread. It's a helpful explaination. As a follow-up, my concern on point 2 - the ip ranges, should i be worried that this ip is in 192.168.0.1 when all the devices in my network are in the .1.x range?

Comment: The vendor lookup of the MAC address shows "TP-Link", maybe this gives you a hint which device to search for.

Comment: @Marco thank you for the response. I'm curious how did you search for the vendor mac address. I pasted the whole address 01:00:5e:00:00:01:90:9a:4a:dc:31:62:08:00
into mac address sites and they kept showing info not found.

May i know if there is something i am missing?

Pardon me, i am still learning. Not well verse with networking stuff at all. 

Thank you!

here's my error: https://imgur.com/a/ygxm77o

Comment: See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/416585/

Comment: Thank you @Marco appreciate your time